# How to populate UITableView with data from a grouped struct in a dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, struct

I have the following struct that contains data from parsed JSON.

```
struct callRailData {
var callDate: String
var userDetails = callData()
}

struct callData{
var callerName: String?
var callerNumber: String?
var callerCityName: String?
var callerCountryName: String?
var callerStateName: String?
var callAnsweredState: Bool?
var callDirection: String?
var callDuration: String?
var callRecordingURL: String?
var callRecordingPlayer: String?
var callSource: String?
var callCompanyName: String?
}
```

I need to display this data in a UITableView with 'callDate' as section header. So I grouped the struct in this dictionary:

```
var user = [callRailData]()

var sections = Dictionary<String, [callRailData]>()
sections = Dictionary(grouping: user, by: { $0.callDate }).
```

I do not know how to display this data in the tableview. How do I get numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection from 'sections'.
Please help I am a beginner in Swift and iOS development.

Comment: Follow this tutorial for populating data on tableview in Swift: https://www.codementor.io/brettr/two-basic-ways-to-populate-your-uitableview-du107rsyx

Comment: i know how to populate data in tableview. I have problem in numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection in this particular case.

Comment: You should not use a Dictionary as the source of your table view, because it does not keep the entries sorting (e.g. accessible via index). Better use an array instead.

Comment: I needed to group data with same 'callDate' to display in sections, so I had to use dictionary. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can use new grouping Function best described here by Brian https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poUZnT7N-Vk 
from here only I first learn the concept of groping and using it in tableview so will not copy paste ans from him just watch the video its only 9 min :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we use array as datasource for tableview. Provide numberOfRows= array count and "cellForRow" datasource object from array.

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont need to do grouping like that..
jus do it like that hope it will work.

```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return user.count
    }
```

it will make sections on the basis of your user count.
    now in every section get one row to show data.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return 1
        }



 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your cell", for: indexPath) as! Your Cell class
         cell.callerNameLabel.text = user[indexpath.section].userdetails.callerName 
        return cell
    }
```

this func will set your sec header title

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
       return user[section].callDate
    }
```